# Trouble starting Play with Artifactory

Tags: jenkins, playframework-2.0, sbt, artifactory

I'm trying to get Play 2.1.3 working on a Jenkins server (in TeamForge). I got my dependencies loaded into our local Artifactory because there's no internet for resolving dependencies. When I try to startup Play, it hangs forever trying to resolve scala-sbt

```
+ /opt/collabnet/PLAY/play-2.1.3/play
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.12.4 ...
```

I don't understand how to configure Play for the initial bootstrap, and I suspect it isn't getting a chance to read my plugins.sbt or Build.scala files where I specified the location of the Artifactory repository. Do I need to do something with sbt.boot.properties or play.boot.properties? How can I get scala-sbt loaded without an internet?